# JMeter: Why status as "Success" is not shown in View Result in a Tree's response Data when JMeter runs in Distributed mode

Tags: performance, jmeter, distributed, test-plan

Testplan when run on Distributed mode in JMeter Version: 2.13, shows blank "Response Data" in View results in a Tree, however, when run locally, I can see Success in Response Data.

JMeter distributed testing is configured on Windows 7 while Server is on Ubuntu based machine.

Is this the expected behavior of JMeter while in Distributed mode or am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design since 2.9.

See:
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

JMeter uses by default StrippedBatch mode:

> StrippedBatch - remove responseData from succesful samples, and use Batch sender to send them.

To test success, you should add a Response Assertion to your request that tests the presence of "success" , this way JMeter will report success wether in local or distributed mode.

Note that you can alternatively switch to Standard mode by updating user.properties:

> mode=Standard

But it is not advised for performances, read:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: Thanks UBIK, that was helpful.